# Is it possible to add vertical functionality to the 3-finger swipe on macOS?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager, multi-touch, magic-trackpad

MBP 15" user - 95% of my input to it is via the trackpad, I LOVE the 3-finger swipe navigation.

Saying "Swipe left/right/up/down" implies the end result of the movement, not the actual direction of my fingers. Swiping right means go to the window right of my current window. Swiping down displays all your windows/desktop background. Swiping up does nothing.

Really all I want, is to be able to **swipe up to Spotify from any window** or have a second set of windows on a level above the current, 1-dimensional horizontal window set.

Made a simple mockup as to what I am describing.

[image: Row of six desktops labelled DESKTOP 1, PDF, CHROME, WORD, DESKTOP 2, PREMIERE, then atop the middle two, another row of two desktops labelled OUTLOOK and SPOTIFY.]

Is there already an app that allows things to work in this manner?

Comment: You might be interested in a window manager like [yabai](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai). You can then map swipes (using bettertouchtool or equivalent) to yabai programming that navigates the way you want.

Comment: I can’t see any reason why Apple would limit an app to use multitouch gestures. The might choose not to implement this in Mission Control or Finder to have other gestures but you could choose any window manager that suits your needs or make one with a free developer account (no need to pay to make your own Mac apps)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have 6 spaces: 2 desktops and 4 full-screen apps.

You could simulate "vertical spaces" with desktops (you'd end up with 4 desktops and 2 full-screen apps).

So instead of full-screening chrome, just make a new Desktop to house it. Open Chrome on the new Desktop and resize its window to fill the entire available space. Then open outlook on top of it and make outlook's window size the full size of the desktop as well.

Then using three finger swipe up, you can exposé both windows and click the one you want.